# Why does my ajax call not recognize the success function

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

Ny Code is working perfectly and i am getting the proper result but my function is showing the error functon instead. I don't know the cause of this

The code for the ajax call is:

```
function Comment_Form(FormId) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")}
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: {% url 'Home' %},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'comment': $("#" + FormId).serialize(),
                'the_effing_id': $('#The_Effing_Id-' + FormId).val(),
            }),
            success: function () {
                $("#Comment ul").prepend()
                alert("Success ?!");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please Comment if more code is required
Thanks a lot

Comment: what does the url look like in javascript? Looks like some kind of template language and...might end up with a space in the url?

Comment: and how do you know it is working? check the networking tab to see response from server. It's suspicious you don't set the `Accepts` or `Content-type` headers